# Sort an array containing a lot of dates quickly

Tags: powershell

I have a huge array which contains dates. The date has the following form: `tt.mm.yyyy`. I know how to sort the array with `Sort-Object`, but the sorting takes a lot of time. I found another way of sorting arrays, but it doesn't work as expected.

My former code to sort the array was like this.

```
$data | Sort-Object { [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($_, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null) }
```

But as I siad before: this way of sorting is too slow. The `Sort()` method from `System.Array` seems to be much faster.

```
[Array]::Sort([array]$array)
```

This code sorts an array containing strings much faster than `Sort-Object`. Is there a way how I can change the above sorting method like the `Sort-Object` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET method will work for dates if you make sure that the array is of type DateTime.

Meaning you should use

```
[DateTime[]]$dateArray
```

instead of

```
[Array]$dateArray
```

when you create it. Then you can use

```
[Array]::Sort($dateArray)
```

to perform the sort it self...

Comment: Thanks for helping. I got another issue. When I want to put [DateTime[]] in front of my array, means [DateTime[]]$array, and $array contains dates, the output is Montag, 1. Juni 2015 00:00:00. Do I need to parse the dates in that form?

Comment: No problem. I'm a bit unsure about what you mean regarding parsing. The objects are full DateTime objects, but the parsing rules will perhaps change according to your locale. Do you have problems parsing dates (in string) into DateTime objects?

Comment: I meant converting when I used the word parsing. I am sorry for my mistake. Indeed I have problems parsing the dates. The format is dd.mm.yyyy in thr normal array.  All the elements are Strings. And when I want to parse them into dates, using [DateTime[]] the result is this "Montag, 1. Juni 2015 00:00:00".

Comment: Just to be clear, when using a DateTime array, it can only contain DateTime objects. So if you have the dates in string format, you need to parse that string into DateTime before adding to the array. When you want to use the dates that are IN the array, they behave just like all DateTime objects. If you have problems parsing a date string, try to use [DateTime[]]$array += Get-Date -Year $yearString -Month $monthString -Day $dayString for instance. This means though that you might need to do some string manipulations first :)

Comment: Ok, it worked fine. But when I want to cleanup my custom made variables this code doesn't work anymore. The Garbage Collector doesn't do it's job properly, too, in the ISE after the Script has finished it's job, That's why I use "Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference | Remove-Variable -EA 0" to cleanup everything for myself. But the sorting doesn't work anymore with the cleanup code. Could you help me again?

Comment: I think I need to see your code (or at least part of it) to be able to help you out any further. I suggest you look at my profile and try to contact me through my blog, or create a separate question here on SO for this new problem, then you can give us some examples of your code as well.

Comment: I found another solution to this. After thinking about my problem I came to the conclusion that a hash with a key and value pair works perfectly for me without sorting the items in my arrays. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this and didnt mean to. If you make an edit to the answer I can reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

Your input data are date strings with a date format that doesn't allow sorting in "date" order. You must convert the strings either to actual dates

```
Get-Date $_
[DateTime]::ParseExact($_, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null)
```

or change the format of the string dates to ISO format, which does allow sorting in date order.

```
'{2}-{1}-{0}' -f ($_ -split '.')
'{0}-{1}-{2}' -f $_.Substring(6,4), $_.Substring(3,2), $_.Substring(0,2)
$_ -replace '(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)', '$3-$2-$1'
```

At some point you must do one of these conversions, either when creating the data or when sorting.

I ran some tests WRT performance of each conversion, and string transformation using the `Substring()` method seems to be the fastest way:

```
PS C:\> $dates = 1..10000 | % {
>>   $day   = Get-Random -Min 1 -Max 28
>>   $month = (Get-Random -Min 1 -Max 12
>>   $year  = Get-Random -Min 1900 -Max 2014
>>   '{0:d2}.{1:d2}.{2}' -f $day, $month, $year
>> }
>>
PS C:\> Measure-Command { $dates | sort {Get-Date $_} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 520
Ticks             : 15200396
TotalDays         : 1,75930509259259E-05
TotalHours        : 0,000422233222222222
TotalMinutes      : 0,0253339933333333
TotalSeconds      : 1,5200396
TotalMilliseconds : 1520,0396

PS C:\> Measure-Command { $dates | sort {'{2}-{1}-{0}' -f ($_ -split '.')} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 413
Ticks             : 4139027
TotalDays         : 4,79054050925926E-06
TotalHours        : 0,000114972972222222
TotalMinutes      : 0,00689837833333333
TotalSeconds      : 0,4139027
TotalMilliseconds : 413,9027

PS C:\> Measure-Command { $dates | sort {$_ -replace '(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)', '$3-$2-$1'} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 348
Ticks             : 3488962
TotalDays         : 4,03815046296296E-06
TotalHours        : 9,69156111111111E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,00581493666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0,3488962
TotalMilliseconds : 348,8962

PS C:\> Measure-Command { $dates | sort {[DateTime]::ParseExact($_, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null)} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 340
Ticks             : 3408966
TotalDays         : 3,9455625E-06
TotalHours        : 9,46935E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,00568161
TotalSeconds      : 0,3408966
TotalMilliseconds : 340,8966

PS C:\> Measure-Command { $dates | sort {'{0}-{1}-{2}' -f $_.Substring(6,4), $_.Substring(3,2), $_.Substring(0,2)} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 292
Ticks             : 2926835
TotalDays         : 3,38754050925926E-06
TotalHours        : 8,13009722222222E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,00487805833333333
TotalSeconds      : 0,2926835
TotalMilliseconds : 292,6835
```